# Cannot include script for google autocomplete in vue.js using laravel

Tags: javascript, vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2

I'm using vue.js and implementing google autocomplete in the head section i'm trying to include this script app.blade.php :

```
<head>
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{ config('services.google_maps.key')}}&libraries=places" defer></script>
</head>
```

but when i load my component this script is not found and i'm getting error

```
VM2823 app.js:62045 [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook:
"ReferenceError: google is not defined"
     
    found in
     
    ---> <VueGoogleAutocomplete> at node_modules/vue-google-autocomplete/src/VueGoogleAutocomplete.vue
           <user> at resources/js/components/addUser.vue
             <Root>
```

Comment: Is the `<head>` tag written in the `<template>`?

Comment: @sugars: No template is inside component and i have included script in blade file

Comment: It is possible that the google script is still loading when the component is created, so you can try to dynamically load the script in the component.

Comment: @sugars: Can u please give me some link of how can i include it in my component, i'm using this package: https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps

Comment: here is a [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/20klxrxpjy)

Comment: @sugars: Thanks will google autocomplete also work the same way.

Comment: From the example, it seems that you don’t need to load Google Maps by script tag, you only need to pass in the api key in the component.

Comment: @sugars:i was implementing google autocomplete like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-bardeen-5eock?file=/src/main.js but getting some error